# Find file in a directory based on ID# in filename with ColdFusion 9

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-9, cfdirectory

I've got a page that displays a specific video for donors who receive an email from our foundation. The email uses variable data to create a URL with the donor's ID# from our database like this: `http://www.mysite.com/index.cfm?type=thankyou&id=123456&fn=John`. My page is designed to serve up the personalized video based on the Donor ID#.

I have a folder with the videos. The video naming convention includes the donor ID# `thankyou/thankyou_123456_J_Smith.mp4`.

How do I search the directory and find the file I'm looking for based solely on the Donor ID#?

Do I need to run a cfdirectory, create a list, run a find and then use that info somehow? OR can cfdirectory look for a partial name and match that to serve up the correct file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<cfdirectory action="list" directory="c:\" name="data" filter="#donorId#" />
```

This should do it.  List the files in the directory with a filter ensureing the filename includes the donor ID.

Comment: To expand a bit for anyone else that comes along, I added `<cfset videoDir = ExpandPath( './' ) & URL.type>` to the top of the page and then `<cfdirectory action="list" directory="#videoDir#" name="qVideo" filter="*#URL.id#*" />` - Worked great! Thanks Paul.

Comment: I'm not sure why my post didn't include the *#donorId#* or I just forgot to type that but the quick example I made to ensure this would work had that.  Glad it worked.

Comment: It was there, the `*` wildcard on either side of the donorID was missing. This is a great little ditty. Thanks again.